# Terminal is maxed and can't resize in Odin

Tags: display, pantheon-terminal, release-odin

I was typing and somehow managed to get terminal to max size (not full screen)   No matter what I do I can't resize it. The resize arrows are in the upper right corner but do nothing. I looked online and tried super key + various combinations. Double clicked on title bar, etc..

Nothing worked.  How can I reset it back to defaults?  I looked for an obvious . config file.

Regards,
Don

Comment: Are you able to close the Terminal? Does the size remain the same even after reopening Terminal? 

Comment: Yes. I can close it and it always comes back at max size.

Comment: One of the keyboard shortcuts to maximize a window is [Super]+[ ⇡ ]. Pressing it again should restore the application to its proper size. Alternatively, double-clicking the title bar along the top should do it. It’s odd that the window maintains its size despite being closed 

Comment: Hi.  I did try those as well.  Double clicking the title bar, nor the paired arrows had any effect.  Same for super up arrow.  I looked online and tried all the shortcuts I could find.  At most all I can do is get it to completely go full screen and back to max size

Comment: What is odd is that I can use the search and settings icon in the upper right corner. But not the max size/restore icon.

Comment: To add to this.  I createdf a new account and the terminal program works fine there.  So anyone who knows there the preferences for the terminal are I would appreciate it.  I would reather not re-do this user account   Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Just press the <kbd>F11</kbd> key.

When <kbd>F11</kbd> is pressed, the current application will switch to Full Screen mode and be moved to its own workspace. Pressing <kbd>F11</kbd> again will restore the previous window size.

Comment: Thank you but I did try that as well.   If I create a new user on that same machine it al works fine.  It appears to be that I got into this state and it's been saved in a config file now.  I was hoping someone might know what file.